# Find the infimum of $\int_0^1 |a+bx -\sin(\pi x)|^2dx$, where $a ,b \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to find
$$
\inf_{a, b \in \mathbb{C}} \int_0^1 |a+bx -\sin(\pi x)|^2dx.
$$
To do this, I have the following hint.

**Hint:** Describe the problem in terms of distance, subspace and projection in the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$. You will need to use Gram Schmidt.

Using the inner product in $L^2[0,1]$, I've done that
$$
\inf_{a, b \in \mathbb{C}} \int_0^1 |a+bx -\sin(\pi x)|^2dx = \inf_{a, b \in \mathbb{C}} ||a+bx -\sin(\pi x)||^2_{L^2[0,1]}.
$$
But, I don't know how to use the hint in the rest.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are missing a square in the last term

Comment: Observe that you are minimizing the distance to the span of $\{1,x\}$

Comment: Project $\sin (\pi x)$ to the space spanned by $1$ and $x$ by constructing an orthonormal basis for this space.